# How to read an excel file having IIS path in ASP.NET

Tags: absolute-path

I have a file path in my default.aspx.cs page like this: http://localhost/data/Download/Import/Test.xlsx

I want to read this file using EFPlus library and make some changes. But I am not able to read its content and getting error like "URI Format not supported". If I read file directly from physical path then everything works fine. Below is my code snippet.

Dim newFile As [New FileInfo](http://localhost/data/Download/Import/Test.xlsx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, its not possible to get physical path of a file and read it using any library if we have URL like   http://localhost/data/Download/Import/Test.xlsx. We have to give physical path of server if file is not in same directory where website code exists, only then we can read and access that file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use function `Server.MapPath`, [described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx).  This function generates a path relative to the root folder of your site.  The input starts with a tilde `~`, which means the root. I.e.

```
Server.MapPath("~/images")
```

will return a string pointing to your /images folder.

Comment: But my file is not in same location where my website code is, its on another folder outside the website folder which is managed by virtual directory

Comment: Then don't use the tilde. Use an absolute path pointing to the virtual directory, I.e. `/myvirtualdirectory/myfile.xlsx`